# Vue lifecycle hooks in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I have a few Vue components in my otherwise Rails app and I noticed that the `mounted()` lifecycle hook fires at different times, depending on whether I am routed to the page with the component or am already on the page and I refresh the browser.

It's important because I have some `$refs` variables in the DOM that I need on component initialization.

```
mounted: function() {
    let user = {
      user_type: parseInt(that.$refs.user.dataset.user_type),
      location_id: parseInt(that.$refs.user.dataset.location)
    }
}
```

**This function executes successfully on page refresh, but throws the following error when I am routed there:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined

when it is clearly in the DOM:

```
<div ref="user" data-user_type="<%= current_user.user_type %>" data-location="<%= current_user.employee.location_id %>"></div>
```

I know it has to do with timing, but am unsure how to remedy the issue.

Comment: 1) where `that` variable is defined? 2) Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: my apologies for deleting it, I define `that` within the `mounted()` function, above `user`.  And Yes, I am

Comment: I guess your problem is related to turbolinks integration. Try replacing the `that.$refs.user` by `document.querySelector('[ref="user"]')` just as a test. You will see that your code will work. Let me know the result

Comment: It returns a `null` value.  If I run that after the page loads it still returns `null` so I don't think the query is correct

Comment: Thanks to your response I thought to use jQuery for the data-attributes and that worked!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pull down the information using jQuery:

```
let user = {
  user_type: $('[data-user_type]').data('user_type'),
  location_id: $('[data-user_type]').data('location')
}
```